# Install Apache Giraph on a machine with no internet connection

Tags: maven, hadoop, giraph

I want to install **Apache Giraph 1.1.0** on a RedHat cluster, **Hadoop 2.7.1** is already installed and configured on the cluster. In the official tutorial http://giraph.apache.org/quick_start.html, it is recommended to download source code of Giraph and use **Apache Maven** to compile Giraph (needs internet connection), However, The cluster is not connected to internet. My question is : Is there any way to install Giraph on a machine without internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

Build the Giraph source code on a machine with Internet connection according to your hadoop version. Then, copy the jar file (I guess giraph-1.1.0-for-hadoop-2.7.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar) to the master machine of your RedHat cluster. Add this jar file to the hadoop classpath.

Comment: Or download the source code, copy it to the cluster, and build it there.